# selectable textview in recycleview, auto scoll to top when viewpager switchback

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, textview

I have a ViewPager that contains several instances of the same fragment, which only contains a recycleview. the item in this recycleview only contains just one textview with android:textIsSelectable="true".
if i scroll recycleview to mid of one item, then switch viewpager to next page, then switchback, this recycleview will auto scroll to the top of that item.
if i delete android:textIsSelectable="true", this recycleview will hold position.
how can i prevent scroll if i should make this textview text selectable?

Comment: what do you mean by scrollrecyclerview to mid of one item, how big is your one item?

Comment: more then ten lines